# Akka design for Scraping

Tags: c#, akka, akka.net

I am currently learning to create distributed software with Akka, the program i am trying to make is a scraping program. The main challange i have is that i need control over how many simunitanies reqests that goes to the same host, so i will not get banned from the sites. As i have never used Akka before to any real extends could i really use some help with my design, if it is good or completly missed the point.

My design idea is to make a router, for each host, with the amount of routess that i want to continues hit the site with. With a cordinating actors to send the request to the right router.

As my Cordinator is a normal actors, can it only route one request at the time, are there a way to make it able to route multible requests at the time like the router, so it will not be a buttle neck?

[image]

My idea in code.

```
public class HttpRequestCordinator : ReceiveActor
{
    private Dictionary<string, IActorRef> hostDownloader; 

    public HttpRequestCordinator()
    {
        hostDownloader = new Dictionary<string, IActorRef>();

        this.Receive<HttpRequestMessage>(r =>
        {
            this.OnHttpRequesetMessage(r);
        });
    }

    private void OnHttpRequesetMessage(HttpRequestMessage message)
    {
        var host = message.Address.Host.ToLower();
        if (!hostDownloader.ContainsKey(host))
        {
            IActorRef child = Context.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new HttpRequestActor()).WithRouter(new RoundRobinPool(1, new DefaultResizer(0, 10))));
            hostDownloader.Add(host, child);
        }
        hostDownloader[host].Tell(message, Sender);
    }
}
    public class HttpRequestActor : ReceiveActor
    {
        public HttpRequestActor()
        {
            Receive<Messages.HttpRequestMessage>(async r =>
            {
                try
                {
                    CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
                    using (var handler = this.GetHandler())
                    {
                        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
                        {
                            AddDefaultHeadersToClient(client);
                            cancellationToken.CancelAfter(r.TimeOut);
                            var result = await client.SendAsync(r.Message, cancellationToken.Token);
                            Sender.Tell(result);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    Sender.Tell(new HttpRequsetFailed(r));
                }
            });
        }

        private HttpClientHandler GetHandler()
        {
            return new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                UseCookies = false,
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
            };
        }

        private void AddDefaultHeadersToClient(HttpClient client)
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "da-DK,da;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("AcceptCharset", "utf-8");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you find an answer on your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a throttling level between Coordinator and DownloadRouter http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/throttle.html

though I'm not sure if this is implemented in akka.net out of the box